# discrepancy between source code and actual web page

Tags: php

I have coded a math quiz mostly in PHP which pulls 10 questions and answers randomly from a database of about 20 questions.

This works fine, however when I click on "view source code", the source code displays DIFFERENT questions than the ones displayed on the actual webpage. It seems to show other random questions from the database. Does anyone know why this happens?

Here is the link to the quiz: http://socialsoftware.purchase.edu/nicholas.roberts/mathquiz/mathselect.php?category=Calculus

Notice how the source code shows different data than the actual webpage...

Comment: Use `Inspect element` instead of viewing the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you 'View page source', the browser issues a new request, so you get a new random set of questions in the source.

It's different when you choose 'inspect element'. If you do that, you are inspecting details of the current document, not as it was loaded, but as it currently is in the DOM in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

This is because on every refresh, you are fetching 10 random questions. In some browsers, view-source fetches fresh copy of page source. So your script is returning random questions again.

Use inspect element (Developer tools) instead of view source.

Answer (score 1):

When you view the page source, your browser will issue another request to the server. The page source you are viewing then contains a new random set of questions.

If you need to inspect the page currently loaded, use `inspect element` instead.

[image: Fiddler dump]